# Select the same new element after insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript

Using native Javascript. After adding a new element via `insertAdjacentHTML`, I want to select that element itself (`<div id="two">two</div>`). How do I get that without having to search through the DOM?

```
// <div id="one">one</div>
var d1 = document.getElementById('one');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="two">two</div>');

// At this point, the new structure is:
// <div id="one">one<div id="two">two</div></div>
```

Comment: [`d1.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)

Comment: @squint Ah crap, wrong code. Please look again.

Comment: [`d1.lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

as per the docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

'beforeend'

Inserts the new element Just inside the element, after its last child. Hence making it the new last child.

you can use lastChild on the d1 element.

```js
var d1 = document.getElementById('one');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="two">two</div>');
console.log(d1.lastChild)
```

```html
<div id="one">one</div>
```

Comment: @Victor Updated the answer as per the edited question

Comment: If you are sure you adding an element, it's safer to use `.lastElementChild` instead of `.lastChild`

Comment: This doesn't select all the inserted nodes if the HTML being inserted is multiple nodes: `d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="two">two</div><div id="three">three</div>');`

Comment: @lschult2 it selects the last added, so in the loop of adding each node, you need to call .lastChild after each call to insertAdjacentHTML, then if you want all elements, just add each .lastChild to an array.

Comment: In this example, there is no loop adding each node.  There is just one call to insertAdjacentHTML with a string containing multiple elements.  Just pointing this out, as if the number of inserted children is not known in advance, then you can't select everything that was inserted using just .lastChild.